# Recover git branch deleted both locally and remotely

Tags: git

I was in charge of organizing a repo which had many branches to spare and during the merges I didn't notice that a branch didn't fully merge properly but at the time I deleted it both locally and remotely. Is there any way possible to recover this branch?

Comment: No backups, presumably ?

Comment: Were any other branches created locally or remotely from this now deleted branch?

Comment: Have you ever checked out the branch locally?

Comment: @PaulR Indeed I did not backup.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not that I know of.

Comment: Then you may have to do some fishing in the reflog.  Not the end of the world assuming you can find the missing commits.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-765757540.html

Comment: @kan Cheers for the link, the **--unreachable** argument in **git fsck** was the one that helped me pull the branch through.

Answer (score 0):

There is many way, providing you didn't removed it too long ago.

1. When you delete it, it says "was [short_commit_id]". If you can find that message, just use the command

   ```
   git branch mybranch [short_commit_id]
   ```

   to recreate the branch
2. If you can't find that message in your log, you can use `git reflog` to find out what the commit was. `git reflog` shows you all the modification that occured to HEAD, which can help you figure out what the last commit of that branch was.

   Once you've figured out, just use the command from 1. to recreate the branch.